# How to fetch id in data from Array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

```
  [
   {
      id: 9222,
      amount: 7,
      customer: [Object],
      plan: 9554,
      status: 'active',
      created_at: '2021-01-30T18:49:35.000Z'
    }
  ]
```

id: response.data.id tried like this,but getting undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array. So the first thing you should do is decide which element of the array you want to get `id` for. Let's say you want the first element, then you would access it like so:

```
data[0].id
```

Also, I'm not sure where you got the `response` part in your question, for that we would need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken to understand your requirement you want to fetch the id from the array from the response this way `response.data[0].id`
if the response is an array then you will need to specify the index for the array